# how to re-render React component each and every time freshly with animation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, single-page-application

Hi I have a Single Page Application,

when we load the page I am creating some animation. If user is in same page and reload this component that animation is not happening. I believe that , since the DOM is not updated without state or props, I think that animation is not happening again.

For reloading , consider that component is coming from back-end.

I am allowed to use state.

I just fiddle the code here. Please consider this component is coming from backend every time.

I tried with this.forceupdate, inside componentDidUpdate  -- It didn't work

and then I added state in parent div with Date.now() like below

```
 constructor(props)
{
   constructor(props)
    this.state={
    time:Date.now()
    }
  }


<div data-value={this.state.time}>
```

Not worked.

I created fiddle for testing. My component is same like in the fiddle. I want to do animation every time the page loads (If above part is not understandable please consider clicking on same URL and load this component with animation on each click )

https://jsfiddle.net/nye3jcz8/

Comment: Check out the answer I posted and let me know if that's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat of a hack solution and is not necessarily great from a performance perspective, but you could assign a random `key` prop to the component. This would essentially cause React to treat it as a new component each time and mount a new replica component in its place which should animate.

Your animation is playing on mount, which is why nothing related to state is working. On a state change, the component updates rather than remounts. The fix above is designed to force an unmount/remount.

That said, you should probably write a function that allows you to trigger this animation at will rather than through lifecycle-manipulation weirdness. You could do this by adding behavior to remove or apply a CSS class, which would allow you to achieve the desired effect and would likely be better from a predictability perspective.

Answer (score 0):

For a component to re-render the best way is to use the `key` prop. Whenever the `key` prop changes, the component unmounts and re-mounts. I see that this is what you are looking for.

I created a small example from your code.
Check it out:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      count: 0
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
    }, 1000);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div key={this.state.count}>
        <div className="drawLine">I am drawing the at top</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Edit compassionate-varahamihira-xcrws]

You can do it your own way, depending on your application.

Comment: This wont work. Because I am not sure when the component will be called again.

Comment: You need to find a value for your key, ofcourse this is the not the solution. This is just to show how it works.

Comment: If you need more help, you need to add more about your code and when exactly you need to update.